# How to query database integrity check duration time (how much time did it take to complete dbcc checkdb)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dbcc-checkdb

How to know how much time did it take to run database integrity check for all databases on a instance.

I simply need when it started and when its finished.

I am able to query when the last check db was performed, but I was not able to query the duration of the check db.

The goal is to concentrate on the longest time and speed it up somehow.

Comment: How are you performing CHECKDB?

Comment: For this particular server it's been set up as maintenance plan.

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface. This very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in comments you mentioned using maintenance plans. Its been a long time, almost over 6 years since i have used maintenance plans to perform database maintenance. But per my knowledge those are tracked under SQL server agent job history , so you can query msdb database to get those metrics.

However i personally recommend doing this via [ola hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-integrity-check.html) integrity checks. It has a very useful parameter called `LogToTable` which will capture all the needed information for your DBCC CHECKDB related metrics. You can then do further analysis on run time and additional info logged.

Note- Using that tool gives you wide range of additional parameters to improve the performance of CHECKDB